# How to make the progress bar update during a loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a progress bar on my screen that I have the value tied to a temporary state. Within my JavaScript that has a loop function that goes through the data on a table I am updating the temporary state at each loop. At the beginning of the script I am unhiding my progress bar.

When I test the script the processing of the data works as expected. However, the progress bar stays hidden until its done and the progress bar value never updates.

Is there something I should be doing to make this work the way I expect? I tried using a delay in the loop as well but it resulted the same.

Here are a few snippets of the code:

```
progressBar1.setHidden(false);

const idCount = table1.displayedData.length;
const mathPercent = 100 / idCount;
const eachPercent = mathPercent.toFixed(3);
...
const array1 = Object.values(formatDataAsObject(table1.data).ID);
...
array1.forEach(value => {
  progressPercent.setValue = progressPercent.value + eachPercent;
```

Answer (score -1):

A few things before dropping a potential solution:
I believe that in terms of Percentage you don't need the eachPercent increment for the toolbar specifically. It is enough to set the maximum number of iterations equals to the table1 rows. Then start with a variable `i=0` (zero) and increment it on each iteration by one.
Now the key thing, `if (maxnumberiterations % i === 100)` then update the progress bar with i value.
`if(i<maxnumberiterations )` then stop (check the fiddle to understand the loop)

Just in case and for understanding purposes this is how you loop on each item

```
  (function loop() {
        
        i++;
        if (iterations % i === 100) {
            progressbar.set(i); 
        }           
        if (i < iterations) {
            setTimeout(loop, 0);
        }
        
    })();
```

Here is a complete example and if it does not meet your needs you can change it as needed. Btw, its pure JavaScript + jQuery

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oeL8vd2u/2/)

Comment: I rewrote the idea of what you have here in JS that wont error. But no this doesnt work.

Comment: what happens ? nothing ? error ? result not expected ? appreciate it :)

Comment: Nothing. It actually breaks the code that does work for processing the data but thats it (not to the point of throwing an error though, it just doesnt process the data)